# I need an advice for web developpment

Tags: javascript, java, html, web

I want to code a website, showing 7 elements: one image (that will be changing), and 6 buttons (left, right, up, down, backwards, forwards), as shown in this [example](https://ibb.co/TBXWBxH)

The website should be able to "read" a 6 column file, which will have the following format [example](https://fromsmash.com/mudlckcXLB-c0)

with: 
"ind_img_x" being the index for image x (numeric index) 
"url_img_x" being the string containing the web address for image x

- The file will control which image will appear accordingly with the button that is pressed.
  For example: if the image displayed is "img_2", and the user press the "down" button, then the website will show the image 77452, and wait for the next button to be pressed.
- The file will be rather big, able to contain several million lines (for example 10 million lines).
- I should be able to update the file from time to time.
- The web site will have to be able to get each image from the web (by means of the url in the file) The url data may consists of strings of large length. And the website has to be able to read these long strings and urls.

Would somebody please give me some advice about the best web developing language  to use? 
Do you think I'll be able to drop the file into the server as a text file, and ask the web site to read it each time, or will I have to put the data in a database?

I look forward to any advice that you guys may have,

Thank you!

Comment: The kind of app do not really help when choosing the toolset. What influences it is your own skillset, the usage (number of users), the sustainability, the scalability, the performances you need, etc...

Comment: Seblor, thank you for your advice. My skillset is very limited either with java, javascript and/or with sql, so I'll be learning from scratch. The number of users may be really high, anyone that will be entering to the web site should be able to change de pictures by using the buttons. I have to be able to easily update the data set. Performance has to be good, in order to be able to change images (which will be referenced by using url), very fluently. And if the site is responsive and working with different platforms and navigators, that will be perfect!

Comment: If you're learning from scratch and you already know JavaScript I think node.js with the express framework is a great way to learn the webserver side of things.

Comment: Thank you Chris Rollins! I guess that JavaScript alone would probably not be able to load big amounts of data in memory (the file may contain more than one million of lines), but by using node.js that would be possible (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way would be to use a webhosting service and parse the file with JavaScript. Especially because you said you already have JavaScript knowledge.
I would also suggest you to use CSV files: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Edit: When you have millions of lines you should use a database and use Nodejs libraries to connect to the database. Files are only recommended for small sets of data.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comment NoNickAvailable! I'm starting to think that JavaScript and node.js will be the best option.